# How to seamlessly align block divs of different sizes?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I want to create a `div` box 'grid' so to speak.

Currently my `div` boxes are not aligning correctly. `div` boxes of different height cause a large vertical space in between some `div`s. The `div` boxes are also going more to the right side.

I want the `div` boxes to keep the same margin from each other regardless of the height of the boxes and for them to line-up from the left > right.

I want the `div` boxes to align something like this:

[image]

Here's the example of what's happening: http://jsfiddle.net/P4S8z/

HTML:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding: 0 10px 0;
  color: #666;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.box h3 {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  width: 260px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  left: -15px;
  top: 8px;
  color: #cfcfcf;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #111;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #333;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box" style="height:225px;">
    <h3>Blah blah</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="height:160px;">
    <h3>Blah blah</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="height:200px;">
    <h3>Blah blah</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="height:180px;">
    <h3>Blah blah</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="height:150px;">
    <h3>Blah blah</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="box" style="height:170px;">
    <h3>Blah blah</h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i think you will need javascript/jquery solution for this, e.g. http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: You'll have to put your divs into three different columns, otherwise there may be an interaction between them.

Comment: column CSS or masonry script as said earlier : http://jsfiddle.net/P4S8z/3/

Comment: Thank you all. The masonry script does the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of using pure CSS would be to designate columns.

I surrounded each "column" with a div, and floated those divs left.

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Renson/P4S8z/4/

This should keep the margins equal like you wanted

New HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="subcontainer">
    <div class="box" style="height:225px;">
        <h3>Blah blah</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="height:180px;">
        <h3>Blah blah</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="subcontainer">
    <div class="box" style="height:160px;">
        <h3>Blah blah</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="height:200px;">
        <h3>Blah blah</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="height:150px;">
    <h3>Blah blah</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="box" style="height:170px;">
    <h3>Blah blah</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Added to CSS

```
.subcontainer{
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is actually possible with pure CSS:

```
.container {
    column-count: 3;
}
```

At least in modern browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=column-count

Comment: https://codepen.io/rei-of-mf-sunshine/pen/GRmJMpL
Search terms: Two column layout. Grids. Inline-block. different sizes. white space between columns. Grid whitespace, grid repeat auto-fit overflow

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this: (lets say 6 grid columns)
        #subcontainer > div {
            float:left;
            display:inline;
            margin: 0 20px 0 0;
        }
        #subcontainer > div:nth-of-type(6n+6) {
        margin-right: 0;
        }

```
    #ids or .classes with height and width {
    ...
    }
```

That way you are always targeting the 6th child of #subcontainer independent from classes or ids for the right border but center divs will always have the same margin